Help required for an example of a restricted 3,3-SAT problem instance?
"Let r,s-SAT denote the class of instances with exactly r variables per clause and at most s occurrences per variable. We prove the 3,4-SAT result to be the strongest possible and show that 3,3-SAT is in fact trivial." - https://cedric.cnam.fr/~bentzc/INITREC/Files/CB11.pdf
Can someone provide a small example of a satisfiable 3,3-SAT instance such that:

At least one variable occurs exactly 2 times.
The problem instance is satisfiable only if that variable is set to 1.

I tried thinking a bit but couldn't come up with a small example?

What do you mean by small? Is the literal $\neg x$ considered as an occurrence of $x$?

let me correct- 'any finite size' instead of small. Variable occurs 2 times in total: it includes both positive and negated literals. so yes negated ones are also counted.
